# Why $P(X=Y) = 0$ when $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, independent, continuous random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

> If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, independent, continuous random variables, then $P(X=Y) = 0$.

I know that for any particular value $x$, $P(X=x)=0$, but how to show the above rigorously?

Comment: $P (X=Y) = P (X-Y = 0) $

Comment: A limiting argument shows the situation pretty clearly. Suppose that the variables are not continuous but finite with $n$ equally likely possibilities: then $P(x = y) = n/n^2 = 1/n$. Now let $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Actually, "identical" may be a wrong choice of terminology. "Identically distributed" seems better. Because, to me, "identical" means $X\equiv Y$, i.e. $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ for any $\omega\in\Omega$ where $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ is our probability space. And this makes the statement false.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer Thanks, you are right about it

Comment: @G.Snapsmath very clever argument.

Comment: @TomCollinge Clean and clear.

Comment: @G.Snapsmath So you know how to prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are continuous and independent then $P(X-Y=0)=0$? Is the proof any easier than solving the original question?

Comment: @Did Why I think this argument is good is because that $X-Y$ is a new continuous random variable, therefore, the probability that it equal to a particular value is zero.

Comment: @fizis "X−Y  is a new continuous random variable" Why "continuous"? How do you know? This is the whole point...

Comment: @Did suppose $X,Y\in[a,b]$, so that $X-Y\in[a-b,b-a]$

Comment: @fizis OK, let us assume this, if you wish, and then... what? What does this imply regarding the continuity of the distribution of $X-Y$?

Comment: @did Since $X-Y$ can choose any value in the region of $[a-b, b-a]$, the probability that the value fall in this region is $1$. If the CDF is continuous, the probability that it equals to a particular value should be zero.

Comment: @fizis That the CDF is continuous (at 0) is exactly what you want to prove, so every proof which assumes this is flawed, right?

Comment: @Did you are right, I can't proof rigorously that the CDF is continuous.

Comment: @Did I have add my proof, please help to see if there are any flaws

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $$P(X = Y) = E[I\{X = Y\}] = \int \int I\{x = y\}\, dP^X(x)\, dP^Y(y)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon\to0$, $F,f$ be the CDF and PDF of r.v. $X$. From the total probability theorem:
$$
P(X-Y\le \epsilon)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X-t\le\epsilon)P(Y=t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(t+\epsilon)f(t)dt
$$

$$
P(X-Y\le -\epsilon)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X-t\le-\epsilon)P(Y=t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(t-\epsilon)f(t)dt
$$

$$
P(X-Y\le \epsilon)-P(X-Y\le -\epsilon)\approx2\epsilon\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)f(t)dt\to 0
$$

Therefore, the CDF of $X-Y$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Do you mean $P(X-Y \geq -\varepsilon)$? And then calculate $P(X-Y \in [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon])$ in the third line?

Comment: @Therkel The first line is $F_{X-Y}(\epsilon)$, the second line is  $F_{X-Y}(-\epsilon)$, the third line is showing that they are equal in the limit of $\epsilon\to0$

Comment: Then you may have shown that $F_{X-Y}(0) = 0$. What does that have to do with $P(X-Y ~{\color{red}=}~ 0)$? Also, where does your approximation in line 3 come from?

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes in your calculation, starting with the fact that a merely continuous random variable doesn't need to have a density.

Comment: @Therkel $F(t+\epsilon)-F(t-\epsilon)\approx f(t)\cdot 2\epsilon$

Comment: @Dominik then how the total probability theorem writes? I think my idea to solve the problem should be right, the mathematical rigor is loss.

Comment: @Therkel My idea is to show that $F_{X-Y}$ is continuous at $X-Y=0$, therefore it is straightforward to generalize that $P(X-Y\in[-\epsilon,\epsilon])=0$